# Flutter android studio --dart-define not working

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, environment, dart-define

I am trying to pass arguments using --dart-define in the Android Studio IDE, but I am not able to access in the code.

code is

`String.fromEnvironment('ENVIRONMENT', defaultValue: "DEV");`

It is returning defaultValue.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

This is probably a weird gotcha with `String.fromEnvironment`, from the docs:

> This constructor is only guaranteed to work when invoked as const

So this only works if you use

```
const String.fromEnvironment('ENVIRONMENT', defaultValue: "DEV");
```

Comment: lol it's really a gotcha
this works, thanks

Answer (score 3):

change this

```
--dart-define=ENVIRONMENT=PROD
```

to this

```
--dart-define ENVIRONMENT=PROD
```